# Morphing gums in three.js

Tags: three.js

I need to move some teeth within a mouth, and I want the gums to morph to accommodate the new position of the teeth. Does three.js have the functionality for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, here is a simple example:

threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets.html

But it's not that simple with your teeth & gum example.